# Oracle APEX - retrieve default report_id for an IG

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex21.2

I want to retrieve a `report_id` for the default report for an IG. I tried using `apex_application_page_ir_rpt` APEX view but there is no data there for that specific application. How can I programmatically find a default report ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best place to start is the view `APEX_DICTIONARY`. For interactive grid related views, search for any names that have the string 'IG' in them (view with 'IR' reference interactive reports only).

```
select distinct apex_view_name from apex_dictionary where apex_view_name like '%IG%'
```

The logical view name that sticks out is `APEX_APPLICATION_PAGE_IG_RPTS`. The following query will give all available info for a saved report:

```
select * from APEX_APPL_PAGE_IG_RPTS WHERE page_id = <yourpageid> and application_id = <>yourappid and type = 'PRIMARY';
```